# Debian 12 (bookworm) from iPXE

Tags: ipxe, debian-bookworm

I used this guide to setup my iPXE server: https://linuxhint.com/pxe_boot_ubuntu_server/
It is set up on a virtual Ubuntu (20.4.6) desktop system and, after some testing, it works perfectly for PXE booting and installing Ubuntu 22.4 and 20.4 on different client systems.

However, I can't get Debian (12.2.0) to work.

I downloaded the following full (3.7GB) iso:
https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-12.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
and extracted it to /os-images/debian-12.2.0-amd64

Then I edtited the boot.ipxe file and added a debian menu item:

```
:debian-12.2.0-amd64  
set os_root os-images/debian-12.2.0-amd64  
kernel tftp://${server_ip}/${os_root}/install.amd/vmlinuz  
initrd tftp://${server_ip}/${os_root}/install.amd/initrd.gz  
imgargs vmlinuz initrd=initrd.gz ip=dhcp root=${server_ip}:${root_path}/${os_root}  
boot
```

Now it partly works:

On my client it boots into the selection menu.
When I choose the Debian installation it does start the debian installer.
It asks me 3 questions (language, country and keymap) which I answer with the defaults.
Then, after a short screen where it detects installation media, it waits a few seconds on a blue streen, and a notification appears:

> [!!] Detect and mount installation media

So, it looks like the installer cannot find the debian media.
I tried a lot of different arguments in the `imgargs` using google.
However, it seems I can't find the same system setup for the iPXE environment I have.
Most examples all use the netboot.tar.gz, or are examples with older Debian versions.
I'm not sure, but I think the examples I can find don't apply on the setup I have, because it is already booting from TFTP. Am I right about that?

I do like to install it from local media, because this network is intended to be disconnected from the internet. However, if it is too difficult, I will also be able to use remote media, as long as I can integrate it with the current (working) solution for the ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work, thanks to the pointers of Martin.
Its now a non-local solution (so you'll need an internet connection at the client to dowload the installation media), still working on local installation media and preseeding. I will update this post if I got that to work.

As in my original post, I set up an iPXE environment following [this](https://linuxhint.com/pxe_boot_ubuntu_server/) guide. If you don't need Ubuntu, skip the last steps where you download the iso, copy it to the /os-images folder and add it to the menu in the boot.ipxe file.

If the PXE environment is set up, make a folder where you want to put the debian netboot files, download the debian netboot tarball into it, unpack it and clean it up:

```
sudo mkdir -pv /pxeboot/os-images/debian-12.2.0-amd64-netinst      
cd /pxeboot/os-images/debian-12.2.0-amd64-netinst
sudo wget https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzvf netboot.tar.gz
sudo rm netboot.tar.gz
```

I followed [this](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/NetbootFirmware) example, this will also create links which are probably not necessary for this environment, but i did it anyway:

```
sudo ln -s debian-installer/amd64/grubx64.efi .
sudo ln -s debian-installer/amd64/grub .
```

At this point, I started testing (boot.ipxe menu item will follow underneath) and found out that my client PC needed some additional drivers for the NIC. What I did is add all drivers from the tarball firmware.cpio.gz, but I think you can probably also add only specific ones. The complete set makes the startup pretty slow, because the client has to download them all.
In short: you have to add the drivers to initrd.gz
This is how I did that:

```
cd debian-installer/amd64
sudo [ -f initrd.gz.orig ] || sudo cp -p initrd.gz initrd.gz.orig
sudo [ -f firmware.cpio.gz ] || sudo wget https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/firmware/bookworm/current/firmware.cpio.gz
sudo bash -c 'cat initrd.gz.orig firmware.cpio.gz > initrd.gz'
```

Edit boot.ipxe:

```
sudo nano /pxeboot/config/boot.ipxe
```

Add the debian installer menu item:

```
:debian-12.2.0-amd64-netinst
set os_root os-images/debian-12.2.0-amd64-netinst/debian-installer/amd64
kernel tftp://${server_ip}/${os_root}/linux
initrd tftp://${server_ip}/${os_root}/initrd.gz
imgargs linux initrd=initrd.gz ip=dhcp root=${server_ip}:${root_path}/${os_root}
boot
```

Now my client boots nicely into a working debian installer.
As mentioned before, now I will find out how to add the preseed, and maybe using local installation media after that.
If someone knows already how to do that: plz let me know!

**Update:**
Managed to get the preseed working too. Had a lot of trouble retrieving that from tftp but it seems like the network interface is not up when it tries to retrieve the preseed file.
My debian menu item in poot.ipxe is now as follows:

```
:debian-12.2.0-amd64-netinst
set os_root os-images/debian-12.2.0-amd64-netinst/debian-installer/amd64
kernel tftp://${server_ip}/${os_root}/linux priority=critical interface=auto netcfg/dhcp_timeout=200 language=en country=NL locale=en_GB.UTF-8 keymap=us preseed/url=tftp://${server_ip}/preseeds/preseed-deb12.2.0.cfg
initrd tftp://${server_ip}/${os_root}/initrd.gz
boot
```

Note that withouth the `priority=critical` and  `netcfg/dhcp_timeout=200` it fails to get the preseed file.

You need to add the /pxeboot/preseeds folder and wget the example preseed file into that:

```
sudo mkdir /pxeboot/preseeds
cd /pxeboot/preseeds
sudo wget https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/example-preseed.txt
sudo cp example-preseed.txt preseed-deb12.2.0.cfg
```

Now it is set-up and you can edit the preseed file as your configuration needs:

```
sudo nano preseed-deb12.2.0.cfg
```

You can find some preseed info [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/apbs04.en.html)

Comment: Please not just paste the link, if the link gets dead, its not possible to prove - i agree with this wonderfull huge answer, but cititions are sometimes additional greatful to understand this

Answer (score 0):

Not every iso is bootable over network, using NFS to mount the root file system - the issue here is not the pxe environment, it is the debian-installer. I tested the iso above in my environment and ran into the same issue like you did.
With a shell, I found out that the installation system did not even have a network card driver loaded at that moment, so that made it quite obvious why the rootfs could not be mounted - the installer lacked the kernel modules required to access the network - which is probably the reason why all the documentation refers to using `netboot.tar.gz` when it comes to a network install.

Comment: Makes sense!  I tried to download the netinstaller:  [link](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-12.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso)  And updated the boot.ipxe:  
:debian-12.2.0-amd64-netinst  
set os_root os-images/debian-12.2.0-amd64-netinst  
kernel tftp://${server_ip}/${os_root}/install.amd/vmlinuz  
initrd tftp://${server_ip}/${os_root}/install.amd/initrd.gz  
imgargs vmlinuz initrd=initrd.gz ip=dhcp root=${server_ip}:${root_path}/${os_root}              
boot'

With the same effect (installer cannot detect installation media)

Comment: the netinst image is made for loading the debian system from the internet, but that does not mean it supports booting the small netinst linux via NFS... If you are interested, unpack the initrd and see if it contains code to mount a NFS filesystem (compare with an ubuntu image, they have code inside their init infrastructure for that)

Answer (score 0):

The vanilla answer (such as for VirtualBox) is much simpler than @Vinnie230979's answer. All you need to do is extract the files from https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz and put it into a directory you use for booting images.

In my case I'm using PXELinux. My default has this:

```
menu begin Debian 12 
  LABEL Install Debian 12   
  MENU LABEL Install Debian 12   
  KERNEL images/debian12/debian-installer/amd64/linux   
  APPEND vga=788 initrd=images/debian12/debian-installer/amd64/initrd.gz 
menu end
```

The *debian-installer* directory from the tar file was put into my debian12 directory under *images*, where I have ISOs and such.